# How do I connect to the database with out using the mysql_connect when creating the new module in PrestaShop

Tags: php, mysql, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am using the below code to connect to the database in the module to write the several database queries which are not correct it seems, so please tell me what is the correct way of connecting to the database from the new module.

```
$con = mysql_connect(_DB_SERVER_, _DB_USER_, _DB_PASSWD_);
mysql_select_db(_DB_NAME_);
```

Comment: Please read [documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Best+Practices+of+the+Db+Class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, before read this guidelines to create a new module: [How to create a module](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+PrestaShop+Module)

And then this: [Best practices of the Db Class](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Best+Practices+of+the+Db+Class)

Including the files like the `elPresta` says it's old and deprecated method, after that to make a simple query, read what he wrote `Matteo Enna`.

Answer (score 1):

use

```
$query ="select * from name_table"; /*example query*/
Db::getInstance()->executeS($query);
```

you do not need anything else to make a query

Comment: include('/../../config/config.inc.php');
include('/../../init.php');
$db = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_); still not connected to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Just include these files and thats it!

```
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../config/config.inc.php');
include(dirname(__FILE__).'/../../init.php');
```

And after all you can use methods as Matteo told u. Or read more here ( http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/DB+class+best+practices )

Comment: include('/../../config/config.inc.php');
include('/../../init.php');
$db = Db::getInstance(_PS_USE_SQL_SLAVE_);   still the connection is not done

Comment: It should be. Have you checked if its correct path? You must include config.inc.php and init.php files - that`s it.

And try get something from shop for example:
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM '._DB_PREFIX_.'shop';
$results = Db::getInstance()->ExecuteS($sql);
var_dump($results);